# Android: How to save image from camera to gallery of device?

Tags: android

I would to save image from camera to storage of device and show them in gallery. I read somewhere that the gallery is a native android app designed to show the image and video files on the SD card, so it's impossible to save photos/videos directly. I'm using provider but it doesn't show photos/videos to gallery. How can I solve my issue?
This is my code so far:

```
public class NewCameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button photoButton;
    private Button videoButton;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private File photoFile = null;
    private File videoFile = null;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "NewCameraActivity";
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath = "";
    private String mCurrentVideoPath = "";
    private Uri photoURI = null;
    private Uri videoURI = null;

    private boolean isVideo = false;
    private boolean isPhoto = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_camera);

        imageView =  findViewById(R.id.taken_photo);
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_taken);
        photoButton = findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureImage);
        videoButton = findViewById(R.id.btnTakeVideo);

        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    captureImage();
            }
        });

        videoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                recordVideo();
            }
        });
    }


    private Boolean recordVideo() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
        else {
            Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                try {
                    videoFile = createVideoFile();
                    displayMessage(getBaseContext(), videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.i(TAG, videoFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (videoFile != null) {
                        videoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.example.inbioaiqua.fileprovider",
                                videoFile);
                        isVideo = true;
                        isPhoto = false;
                        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    displayMessage(getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage().toString());
                }

            } else {
                displayMessage(getBaseContext(),"Null");
            }
        }
        return isVideo;
    }

    private File createVideoFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String videoFileName = "MP4_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        File video = File.createTempFile(
                videoFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".mp4",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentVideoPath = video.getAbsolutePath();
        return video;
    }

    private Boolean captureImage() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
        else {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                try {

                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    displayMessage(getBaseContext(),photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.i(TAG,photoFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.example.inbioaiqua.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);
                        isPhoto = true;
                        isVideo = false;
                        videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    displayMessage(getBaseContext(),ex.getMessage().toString());
                }

            } else {
                displayMessage(getBaseContext(),"Nullll");
            }
        }
        return isPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
        else if(requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(String.valueOf(videoFile), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
        } else {
            displayMessage(getBaseContext(), "Request cancelled or something went wrong.");
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(isPhoto == true) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if(isVideo == true) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

files_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.inbioaiqua/files/Pictures" />
    <external-path name="my_videos" path="Android/data/com.example.inbioaiqua/files/Movies" />
</paths>
```

Comment: You should save your images to file in a storage location. If one time Gallery apps will show them is something completely different. Now please rephrase your post and tell where you are able to and where to not

Comment: @blackapps I edited the question and now I hope it's clearer what I would like to do.

Comment: You did not even tell if you can save to storage. I asked you to tell that.

Comment: I would like to save them to storage and by opening the gallery I can see them

Comment: Yes i know. Now we would like to know if your code is able to store your data in a storage location. So can you create files?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I didn't understand what you meant. However, for now, it saves the photos / videos in folder but i can't see them in gallery. I add the provider xml file if it can be useful.

Comment: No not usefull. Now that you saved your file in a folder you should tell the media store that you did so. As Gallery apps query the media store for files.

Comment: So should I scan the folders?

Comment: You should let the media store scanner scan your files right after you created them indeed. You can also reboot your device.

Comment: You use getExternalFilesDir(). That is an app private directory and the media store will not touch it. So invisible for Gallery apps. Even after reboot.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. If I have any problems can I write here again?